# Schengen & insurance

Tags: visas, schengen

Which is it- You apply for a schengen visa from the country you entering first or the country you spending the longest time in? And after the age of 70 is it compulsory to have medical & travel insurance no matter where you travel to and/or from? Where can I find more info re schengen visa application when your spouse is a UK resident & you are a South african resident but wish to travel to Europe together. Been reading too much conflicting info.

Comment: https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/how-to-apply-schengen-visa/

Comment: Medical insurance is obligatory even if you under 70 years.

Comment: Is your spouse a resident of the UK or a citizen of the UK?  It makes a huge difference (as long as the UK remains in the EU).

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply from the country you spend the longest time in. If there are 2 or more countries with the same amount of time, apply from the country you enter first. You need medical insurance.